# nsimageview valueUrl binding is not working

Tags: cocoa, nscollectionviewitem

i am new to cocoa programming. I am having a nsimageview and nstextfield in a nscollectionviewitem. How to update the nsimageview with external url in nscollectionview.
Binding works fine for the nstextfield and not for the nsimageview. After googling i understood the bug is due to key-value observing. How to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Extras -> Perform -> Update -> nscollectionviewitem

Comment: i coudnt get you. Can you explain briefly